# How can a "while remaining" algorithm be converted to functional style?

Tags: algorithm, scala, functional-programming

In my imperative-style Scala code, I have an algorithm:

```
def myProcessor(val items: List) {
  var numProcessed = 0
  while(numProcessed < items.size) {
    val processedSoFar = items.size - numProcessed
    numProcessed += processNextBlockOfItems(items, processedSoFar)
  }
}
```

I would like to keep the "block processing" functionality, and not just do a "takeWhile" on the items list. How can I rewrite this in functional style?

Comment: `def myProcessor(val items: List) { myProcessor(items,items.size())}`; and change the current method to have an extra parameter of size `int` of the current number of items that should be processed, and instead of invoking in a while, recursively invoked. Is something like that functional-style enough in your opinion?

Comment: @amit so it will just run forever?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Of course not, add a stop clause when numProcessed < 0

Comment: @amit Well you didnt say that

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Thought it was implicitly obvious that you add a stop clause when we talk about recursive invokation.

Comment: Does processNextBlock always process the same number of items (except for the remainder at the end)? Or can it vary from call to call?

Comment: @Paul It varies from call to call.

Comment: Some things seem odd, so clarifications sought: processedSoFar seems instead to be 'numberLeftToProcess'? Since it's the size of items - the number processed. Is this correct? So if processNextBlockOfItems processes things left to right, then it will need to do items.size - processedSoFar to recover the index of the first item. So why not pass in numProcessed?

Comment: And of course the idea of a def that returns nothing (and processNextBlockOfItems having side-effects) is inherently non-functional...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this depends on what you consider to be more functional, but here's a version without the 'var'

```
  def myProcessorFunctional(items: List[Int]) {
    def myProcessorHelper(items: List[Int], numProcessed: Int) {
      if (numProcessed < items.size) {
        val processedSoFar = items.size - numProcessed
        myProcessorHelper(items,
            numProcessed + processNextBlockOfItems(items, processedSoFar))
      }
    }
    myProcessorHelper(items, 0)
  }
```

(making it a list of Ints just for simplicity, it would be easy to make it work with a generic List)

I have to say it's one of those cases where I don't mind the mutable variable - it's clear, no reference to it escapes the method.

But as I said in a comment above, processNextBlockOfItems is inherently non-functional anyway, since it's called for its side effects. A more functional way would be for it to return the state of its processing so far, and this state would be updated (and returned) on a subsequent call.  Right now, if you in the middle of processing two different items lists, you'd have the issue of maintaining two different partially-processed states within processNextBlockOfItems...

**Later:**

Still ignoring the state issue, one convenient change would be if processNextBlockOfItems always processed the first block of the items list passed to it, returned the remaining items it had not processed (this is convenient and efficient if using List, so much so I'm wondering why you're using indicies).

This would yield something like:

```
  def myProcessorMoreFunctional(items: List[Int]) {
    if (!items.isEmpty) {
        myProcessorMoreFunctional(processNextBlockOfItems(items))
      }
  }
```

Comment: Running out of time in my refactoring effort to try avoiding side effects, but fortunately there's only ever going to be one item list; the side effects entail display output.  The last suggestion, returning the remaining items, I think certainly is a nice optimization, and I used that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You need to change it to a recursive style wherein you "pass" in the "state" of each loop

```
@tailrec
def myProcessor(items: List[A], count: Int = 0): Int = items match{
  case Nil => count
  case x :: xs => 
    processNextBlockOfItems(items, count) 
    myProcessor(xs, count + 1)
}
```

assuming that "processedSoFar" is not an index. If you can work with the current "head" of the list:

```
@tailrec
def myProcessor(items: List[A], count: Int = 0): Int = items match{
  case Nil => count
  case x :: xs => 
    process(x) 
    myProcessor(xs, count + 1)
}
```

where `process` would only process the current "head" of the `List`.

Comment: Yeah, as I was suggestiong, I didn't want to change it to process one at a time, partly out of laziness but also with the intention of not changing too much of the code elsewhere.  Wouldn't you agree that a "takeWhile" syntax would be cleaner, if it was one at a time?

Comment: Actually, I think I noticed an issue... your code ignores the number of items processed in each block.  It's processNextBlockOfItems, not processNextItem.  If I'm not mistaken, this could be fixed by replacing "count + 1" with "count + returnValueFromBlockProcessing"

Comment: And why do you need the x :: xs in the first case?  It seems like I'd want to pass in a sub-array of "unprocessed items" to myProcessor, rather than just the "list with one removed".  I'm finding it easier just to pass around an indexed list, rather than a "items remaining", and only deal with the indices...  Hmm... I think I'm going to hold out for an answer that better matches the question, although I appreciate your initial response.

Comment: @sdanzig I honestly do not know your code nor how it works other than what you've shown. However, the `x :: xs` is pattern matching to split the list into smaller pieces. If `processedSoFar` is what you are using for indexing, then you have an O(N^2) algorithm. Index look up in a `List` in Scala is an O(N) process. What you should do is structure your code so that it works on just one item at a time.

Comment: I showed a "numProcessed" variable that tracks the number of items processed in each block.  That's the key thing it seems your solution isn't accounting for.  I agree that it's more "functional-friendly" if I can process them one at a time, but I don't think it's insurmountable to implement without complexity.  It seems to work pretty efficiently if you're just passing around the last index processed each recursion though.  If I wanted, I could pass the list with it.  Is that frowned upon by functional purists?

Comment: Why not separate concerns? If you want them grouped into chunks of a fixed size, then call `.grouped` on your list, then operate on the individual chunks (perhaps with a fold).

Comment: @MyseriousDan, They're not fixed size - see the OP's response to my comment to the question